# KendoReact PDF Generator Export Issue

Tags: kendo-ui, pdf-generation, react-typescript

I am using KendoReact PDF Generator to generate PDF files from HTML (client side). since it is working fine on development machine (linux), after moving same to other environment like SIT, QA etc (Linux), the tables exported as pdf behaves unusual and some texts goes little out from table's tds then breaks. also some underline issues can be seen in below image.

Kendu react ui pdf geneartion: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-react-ui/components/pdfprocessing/

Can somebody help me to resolve the issue.

[image]

I am using following following config to generate PDF:

```
savePDF(element, {
          paperSize: "A4",
          scale:0.7,
          margin: 0,
          fileName: newFileName,
        });
```

Comment: Are all the fonts the same? Look at the PDF properties and fonts used in the PDF in both environments and see.

Comment: Yes same configurations on all ENVs, one thing is really interesting that it is generating perfectly on mobile devices. don't know about this behavior.